# What does the @ sign do when preceding a variable in PHP

Tags: php

I see some code that looks like this:

```
if(@$_POST['myvar'])
```

What does the @ sign do in this instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suppresses any and all error messages, warnings, or notifications caused by the expression you've prepended it to. In this case: `if(@$_POST['myvar'])` it is probably being used because the original author did not want a notification to be emitted if `$_POST['myvar']` is unset.

Comment: Correct answer. USAGE: you can add some context to errors you report by using this if a flag on your project is set to enable error reporting. ie: code it so you can switch it on or off. There are inexpensive ways to do this and expensive ones; I prefer the cheap and dirty methods.

Answer (score 6):

It suppresses any warnings/notices/errors from being printed. For instance, if `$_POST['myvar']` we're undefined, PHP may output an `Undefined index` notice. The `@` prevents that behavior.

That being said, it is considered bad practice to arbitrarily suppress warnings. You can, instead, check for the variable being set with `if (isset($_POST['myvar']) && $_POST['myvar'])`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: You should remove the `@` from `isset(@$_POST['myvar']) ` ;)

Comment: Thanks! That was the whole point of using isset but I left it in there accidentally lol –––––––